# AngularJS: Apply another directive in my directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create an `A`-restrict directive `bg-image` (for `button` tags) which replaces itself by another `A`-restrict directives.

So,

```
<button other-attr="other-value" bg-image="'image'">Text</button>
```

should become

```
<button other-attr="other-value" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(\'image.png\');'}">Text</button>
```

How can I do this? Thanks.

Update: I want to apply **directive** but not something like `elem.css`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `elem.css()` and `attr` parameters of the link function to get what you achieve, no need to use the `ngStyle` directive base on the `css` properties you want to be included.

e.g.

```
.directive('bgImage', function() {
  return function(scope, elem, attr) {
    elem.css('background-image', 'url(' + attr.bgImage + ')');
  };
});
```

UPDATE:

Considering the example above you can also use `ngStyle` and have the $compile service to recompile the element together with `ngStyle` directive:

e.g.

```
.directive('bgImage', function($compile) {
  return function(scope, elem, attr) {
    elem.attr('ng-style', "{'background-image': url(" + attr.bgImage + ")}");
    elem.removeAttr('bg-image');
    $compile(elem)(scope);
  };
});
```

removing the `bgImage` directive before compilation prevents the infinite compilation process.

New Update:

**HTML**

```
<button bg-image="my-default-image.png" bg-image-hover="my-hover-image.png"></button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
.directive('bgImage', function() {
  return function(scope, elem, attr) {
   elem.css('background-image', 'url(' + attr.bgImage + ')');

   elem.on('mouseover', function() {
     elem.css('background-image', 'url(' + attr.bgImageHover + ')');
   });

   elem.on('mouseout', function() {
     elem.css('background-image', 'url(' + attr.bgImage + ')');  
   });

   scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
     elem.unbind('mouseover');
     elem.unbind('mouseout');
   });
  };
});
```

As you notice you can do this without appending new directives in the element itself, you can still achieve adding behaviours in a DRY manner.

Note: if you create events within a directive, be sure to clean it when the scope of the directive is destroyed via unbinding it in the `$destroy` event

Comment: Thanks, +1, but I want to apply *directive* because not all directives can be applied the same and simple.

Comment: In short you wan't to append new directives within the directive itself?

Comment: yes. but one important moment: a directive of type `A` (such as `ng-style`) but *not* a directive I can just include in template (such as `ng-form`).

Comment: can you specify a use case on which you want to apply such a methodology, as you mentioned that "not all directives can be applied the same and simple"

Comment: Can append new directives within the directive itself or not?

Comment: Answer: this method is not "simple" because I should duplicate code of `ng-style` directive. Ok, you may name this 'not DRY' but not 'not simple'.

Comment: hmm let me apply the `ng-style` directive instead of using `elem.css()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56531/discussion-between-ryeballar-and--).